# TFS Team build guide

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am trying to use TFS team build, but can't find any decent startup documents/guides.
Can somebody give me some pointers on do's/dont's and maybe a link to a good guide?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The guys here at work use this book:

[Inside the Microsoft® Build Engine: Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626286)

Answer (score 3):

This [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/tags/Team+Build/default.aspx) has some great articles on Team Build including tips on setting on CI builds.  If you're using Team Foundation Server I recommend installing the [Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx) which makes  life much easier.

Answer (score 1):

When I did a lot of work with TeamBuild, [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/aaronhallberg/) would always have the answers I was looking for.  I'm pretty sure I was on it at least once a day.

Answer (score 0):

These two links helped me a lot to understand Build Team.

[A Primer on Microsoft Build Automation](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/03/15/a-primer-on-microsoft-build-automation.aspx)

[Creating a Build Definition in TFS](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/04/11/creating-a-build-definition-in-tfs.aspx)